# How to display Card data in a modal menu react.js 2022 - 2023

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props, conditional-rendering

I have card mapped with data from an "json" file and want the same details on the card to display on the modal menu

In the code snippet is the code for the cards that are displayed and the modal the modal works properly (opens and closes) but I now want to use the data from the cards in the modal but it doesn't show. I used the card key to specify which cards data to use but don't think that it works this way. I am new to react and think I need to use props but can't find any material that can explain it in a way I understand. Please help if you can any critsism will be gladly accepted and any other ways to improve my code will also help. Any learning material will also be hugely helpful.

Code:

```
      {
        details.map((details) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={details.id}>
              <img src={details.image} alt="" />
               <h5 className="board-name">{details.design}</h5>
               <p className="board-size">Size: {details.size}</p>
               <h6 className="board-price">{details.price}</h6>

              <button className="add-to-cart" onClick={() => 
                 setModalDisplay(true)}> click me
              </button>

            </div>
          )
        })
      }

      {modalDisplay && 
            <div className="backdrop">

            <div className="cart-card" key={details.id}>
              <div className="item-details">
                <img src={details.image} alt="" width="98px" height="98px" />
                <h4 className="item-name">{details.design}</h4>
                <p className="item-size">{details.size}</p>
                <h6 className="item-price">{details.price}</h6>
                <button className="exit-modal" onClick={() => 
                  setModalDisplay(false)}>
                </button>
              </div>
              <span className="modal-inputs">
                <button className="minus-btn">-</button>
                <input type="text" className="amount-input" value="01" />
                <button className="plus-btn">+</button>
                <button className="add-btn">Add to cart</button>
              </span>
            </div>
      
          </div>
      }
    </div>
```

Comment: Both Images at CODE EXAMPLE

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as screenshot(s)? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Hi sure I am new and didn't know if you have an solution for my problem and require text then ill do my best to make it easier for you to help thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the card data in an onClick that sets it in an state for example and use the state in the modal as props or directly. I think that would be the best option to use in this case.